# Installation eclipse: failed to create the java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I tried to install java eclipse but I constantly get the error 'failed to create the java virtual machine' I am working on a mac version 10.15.4 and have a JDK version 14 (default on the mac)

Comment: Does "default on the mac" mean preinstalled? Because the last time I checked the newer mac versions don't come with java

Comment: Eclipse does not currently work with Java 14 on macOS. Use Java 13.0.2 or earlier.